# App Store Connect shows wrong build number

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I uploaded a build using the Xcode beta, forgetting that you can't submit builds compiled with beta versions. So I updated to the release version of Xcode via the App Store.

With the Xcode beta, App Store Connect was accurately reflecting the build number (4.8.1). Now with the release version, Connect shows a build number of 5. I tried incrementing in Xcode to 4.8.2, and now Connect showed a build number of 6.

Has this happened to anyone else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a bug, it's a (new) feature.

Your build number must increment on every new build. A lot of people, including you, don't know that. So now, during the build submission, your build number is validated, and it is automatically incremented if necessary.

So that's what happened: your build number was corrected to 5; then you tried to lower it, which is illegal, and submitted again, and it was corrected to 6, which is right.

Note that the build number should be just a number, not a dotted version string.

Also, you can reset the build number to 1 if you up the user facing version string.

Comment: Thanks Matt! Btw, not sure if you downvoted it or someone else, but I definitely searched around before posting and failed to find anything. As you point out, a lot of people don't know about this, so I think it may be useful to leave up for others!

Comment: This feature is called out very clearly in the only place that's meaningful to look: the release notes (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-13-release-notes). "When uploading an app to App Store Connect, the distribution assistant in Xcode detects whether your app has a valid build number..." etc.

Comment: That may be true, but the build number correction only happens in App Store Connect not in Xcode, and to someone who doesn't understand what's going on, feels like a bug not a feature. (also the Xcode release notes are 11,000 words long!)

Comment: I personally think there's a bug in their new system. I uploaded a build with version 211019.1, having the last uploaded being 211019.0, it should have pass their verification (according to the documentation on CFBundleVersion, one to three dot notation), but instead it "bumped" the build version to 211020. Anyone in the same situation ?

Comment: That's what my answer tells you. It's not a bug; it's a feature. CFBundleVersion should represent an integer, plain and simple. Ignore the old docs.

Comment: Where's the new doc ? Since it has not been communicated anywhere and no documentation has been deprecated, this is a bug.

Comment: @DamienBannerot Then report it! https://feedbackassistant.apple.com

Comment: I did report it.

Comment: Excellent, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I experienced the same issue with XCode 13 and finally found the cause: during the process of uploading the archive, you are presented with a dialog that includes a "Manage Version and Build Number" checkbox. By default, it is ticked (i.e. checked). Untick this box to prevent the build number from being auto-managed by Apple.

Comment: And if you forget once, it might destroy your whole chain of build numbers :'(. Really intrusive feature.

Comment: Is there any working way to disable this checkbox by default? I am used to manage build numbers on my own. And this new feature has already broken my expected version a few times...

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a bug.

The release notes just say the build number must be a valid build number and the current documentation for [CFBundleVersion](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleversion?language=objc)  says it is a machine-readable string composed of one to three period-separated integers.

I was using xcrun altool --upload-app to upload my app and after switching to Xcode 13 when uploading my app with version 4.7.123 it automatically "corrected" it to 5.

I am now using xcrun altool --upload-package along with --bundle-version to set the build number which works except that I can no longer upload any version 4.7 apps because the currently uploaded version is 5.